# CSS image background - stretch height to 100% but keep image horizontally centered on page

Tags: css

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

The page I'm working on is here
http://www.iknowpost.com/

What I'm attempting to do is keep the background image stretched to 100% height, regardless of the viewer's screen size, while keeping the image centered horizontally on the page at all times.  As of now I've got the 100% height figured out, but I've been trying unsuccessfully to figure out how to center it horizontally - currently it's fixed left: 0px;  I think this should be pretty simple.  My code is below, and perhaps this isn't the right way of going about this.  Thanks!

```
<style type="text/css">
#background {
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
position: fixed;
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
z-index: -1;
}

.stretch {
    height:100%;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="background">
    <img src="logo.jpg" class="stretch" alt="" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to be working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mK6Ms/  can you show us an example on jsFiddle.net where it does not?

Comment: Also, you may get better results if you create a jsFiddle instead of linking to your site.  I for one will not go to mystery links on SO because I have no idea what is on there.  It also makes figuring out your issue easier.

Comment: Thanks so much Abe.  I'll keep that in mind for future requests... using jsfiddle is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sure there are other ways to add background like that, but in this case add `#background { text-align: center; }` and it will center your image in the provided container.

Comment: Thank you!!!  This did the trick perfectly.  I haven't tried Robert's suggestion but Jonah's suggestion didn't seem to work...  I really appreciate your quick response and this website is amazing.

Comment: this will not work when the image is wider after stretching it's height to 100%

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #background {
            width: 700px;
            height: 100%; 
            margin: 0 auto;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        .stretch{
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <img src="logo.jpg" class="stretch" alt="" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple! just add the following to your `.stretch {}` :

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```